# Building a hotel program database, need a database design opinion

Tags: database, data-modeling

Each reservation contains names of the guests & a company name.

Now, the guests may/may not belong in a company. (a booking may have a company as null)

Currently, I have:

```
Booking_table (booking_id, guest_id, company_id)

Guest_table (guest_id, guest_name)

Company_table (company_id, company_name)

Guest_booking_history (guest_id, booking_id)

Company_booking_history (company_id, booking_id)
```

Am I doing this right? Any suggestions in designing the database?

An alternative would be:

```
Booking_table (booking_id, guest_names, company_id)

Company_table (company_id, company_name)
```

Comment: If both individuals and companies can book rooms, this `Booking_table (booking_id, guest_id, company_id)` isn't the way to do it. What's the predicate for this table supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly good, but I'd consider adding the company to the guest, and *maybe* remove the company from the booking table. Something like:

```
Booking_table (booking_id, guest_id)

Guest_table (guest_id, guest_name, company_id)
```

Other than that, I think your database is missing a lot of important data - dates, customer info, etc, but that's a whole other issue fully dependent on exactly what you want to achieve with the database and software.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it would be usefull to have the booking dates, and booking needs likely needs to be linked to a table of rooms.
It all depends on what data you want to keep and track ;)

Other then that, if this is homework mark it as that.

Comment: I have all that. I am just omitting those fields in my post to simplify my question. Perhaps I should be more specific. I will edit my post. Thanks anyways!